# Mongoose plugin not working when used in combination with Feathersjs

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, feathersjs

I have a very annoying problem with a Mongoose plugin in combination with Feathers.

It is a straight forward plugin that is taken from the Mongoose documentation [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#versionKey) that updates the document version (__v) on every type of update. It works fine as standalone plugin, but when combined with Feathersjs it fails.

Somehow Mongoose is not converting the object id strings to ObjectIDs correctly when running updates and patches with the plugin in combination with Feathersjs. If I disable the plugin updates and patches do work.

As far as I have been able to determine debugging, the data sent in the call from Feathersjs to Mongoose is the same both with the plugin enabled or disabled. So I'm inclinded to say that Feathersjs is not the culprit, but then again why does the plugin work without Feathersjs?

I have setup an example repo [here](https://github.com/nidkil/feathers-mongoose-plugin-issue). Unfortunately this is the minimum setup required to recreate the problem. The stup is as follows:

- src/models/schema/categories.schema.js - The example Mongoose schema
  definition
- src/mongoose/always-update-version-key.js - The plugin
- test/mongoose/always-update-version-key.test.js - Test the schema and
  plugin without Feathers
- test/services/category.test.js - Test the schema and plugin with Feathers

I have added the test to test the plugin with and without Feathersjs. To run the tests execute `npm run test:unit`. Mongo must be running on the default port (27017).

I hope someone can help me solve this very frustrating problem or point me towards the code in Mongoose where the id strings are converted to ObjectIDs.

Answer (score 0):

The default setting of `feathers-mongoose` is the [`lean` option](https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-mongoose/#serviceoptions) set to `true` for faster queries. When model plugins should be used (which I think should be the case here), set `lean: false` in the [service options](https://github.com/nidkil/feathers-mongoose-plugin-issue/blob/master/src/services/category/category.service.js#L10-L13):

```
  const options = {
    Model,
    paginate,
    lean: false
  };

  // Initialize our service with any options it requires
  app.use('/category', createService(options));
```

Comment: Hi Daff, I made the change unfortunately it did not solve the issue :-( I also wonder how it would help, as the call that utilizes the lean option is called after the call that fails.

See line 189  and line 195 of feathers-mongoose/lib/service.js.

Comment: Hi Daff, I have figured out a solution that requires a change to feathers-mongoose/lib/service.js. I have updated the issue on GitHub (https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers/issues/1060). Do you have time to check it out?